# How to move coupon code to shipping step of checkout in Magento 2?

Tags: checkout, discount, coupon, onestepcheckout

I am trying to move coupon code to shipping step instead of payments & review step. how this can be implemented?

I need discount code form to appear in shipping step after shipping methods display.

Comment: Please specify Magento version in your question.

Comment: i am using 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Create a checkout_index_index.xml file in Module_Name/view/frontend/layout

uiComponent
                                            
                                                
                                                    
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                
                                                                    Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount
                                                                    
                                                                        
                                                                            0
                                                                            Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages
                                                                            messages
                                                                        
                                                                        
                                                                            Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/captcha
                                                                            captcha
                                                                            sales_rule_coupon_request
                                                                            checkoutConfig
                                                                        
                                                                    
                                                                
                                                            
                                                        
                                                    
                                                
                                            
                                        
                                        
                                            
                                                
                                                    
                                                        
                                                            
                                                                
                                                                    
                                                                        true